# this item is not compatible with your device (Galaxy S3)

Tags: android, android-manifest, galaxy

I publish a Android app on play.google.com and my app manifest setting like that;

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:resizeable="false" 
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Everything is ok but today when i check app on play.google.com with Galaxy S3, responsing this message :
"this item is not compatible with your device"

Galaxy S3 spec;
Android 4.0.4
Without simcard

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Maybe the S3 counts as large screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers, and the problem is just about my device (test device)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:xlargeScreens="true"` to `supports-screens`

The Galaxy S3 has a resolution of  1280×720, which counts as `xlarge`/`xhdpi`

Comment: You could (a) exclude particular tablet devices in the Market/Play console or (b) set `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />`, since 99% of tablets don't have a phone-feature